# MonoTouch: Appearance is 4.3 safe?

Tags: c#, ios, mono, xamarin.ios, appearance

Though 4.3 users of iOS devices are rare these days, do we need to check before we assign values to the various `Appearance` classes using `MonoTouch 5.2.x` or will the MonoTouch framework just gracefully ignore these settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MonoTouch (just like Objective-C) does not does version checking inside API. That would be very **costly** to do and, in many cases, it cannot be done reliably (e.g. a new `PushSomething` methods).

Even when it could be possible to ignore at runtime, e.g. types that conforms to `UIAppearance` protocol, the application might want to adjust itself differently if it's not supported (e.g. color choice). E.g.

```
if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion (5,0)) {
    UISlider.Appearance.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Black;
} else {
    // limited UI customization path
}
```